# Run Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 Remote Debuggers simultaneously as service

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2022

My team has a blend of VS2019 and VS 2022 users and I would like to configure our servers to run remote debuggers for both versions. I've tried starting both services but get the following error.

[image]

The only solution I've found thus far is to run 2019 as a service and 2022 as an application. Ideally, I could run both as a service. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!